# Twilio Remote view (TVIVideoView) is blank on the reciever side

Tags: ios, swift, twilio, arkit

I have integrated twilio programmable video in my sample app.
I have 2 apps and both joins the same room.
On the publishing side it works just fine. I am using AR camera instead of a normal one. I am able to view the preview of the other person and audio also works fine.
But on the receiver side, the remote view seems to be blank. It doesn't load the other person's back camera view itself. The same code was working before and it suddenly stopped working.

Please find the swift file that has the receiver code in the below url,

https://www.dropbox.com/s/j0uxt3cv5iqznc0/ARHelpViewController.swift?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you subscribe to a `TVIRemoteVideoTrack`, you also must wait for the `subscribedToVideoTrack:publication:forParticipant:` callback to confirm that you are truly subscribed to the video track and that the data will then be forthcoming.

You can also query `hasVideoData` to determine whether frames have been received for that view already.

I also believe that a known limitation in the current implementation of `TVIVideoView` is that if you reuse a view by adding it as a renderer to a different `TVIVideoTrack`, the `1hasVideoData` property will not be reset and no `videoViewDidReceiveData:` will be sent. The work around for that is to make a new `TVIVideoView` for any `TVIVideoTracks` that you wish to render.

I'd also maybe recommend checking out this [blog post on ARKit with Twilio Video](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/10/ios-arkit-swift-twilio-programmable-video.html) or this [blog post on ARKit with Twilio Video and the Data Tracks API](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/10/build-shared-ar-with-twilio-video-arkit-and-data-track.html).